# Is it possible to de-upgrade from Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakketi Yak) to 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) ?

Tags: 16.04, 16.10

I'm a little bit of a newbie here and I apologize for that. So I've been looking for someone who has the same issue and stuck with Ubuntu 16.10 which is not being supported at the moment. I can't really update anything nor update the O.S as the host is completely shut down. So I came to the conclusion that I must re-download Ubuntu 16.04 and just reinstall the whole thing from scratch. But before I do anything I just want to make sure if there's any alternative way. 
Thank You!

Comment: Usually it's recommended to not mix LTS releases and regular releases.

Comment: A reinstall is the recommended path for the downgrade you propose. You seem to be on the right track. Remember to back up all your data first!

Comment: hehe alright and well I don't have anything to backup though so I got no problem with that just have to wait till the download is done :D

Comment: I can confirm: Downgrading is usually not possible.  A complete reinstall is usually what you have to do in these cases.

Comment: Why can't you roll on to 17.04 and then 17.10?